# my own jQuery plugin with absolute positioned components

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, position

I am building my own jQuery-plugin. My jQuery-Plugin creates a set of slider, buttons and other visual components lying in a 'div'. The 'div' is the only thing needed in the html-code. All other visual components are created dynamically.

My problem: I want to use absolute positioning for the dynamically created components. But that means the 'div' in the html-code is not allowed to have a static position. But I don't want to dictated the user of my plugin to use only non-static positioning in his design. What could I do? Do I have to use static positioning in my jQuery-plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap all of your components with a `div` element and give it `relative` position and append newly created `div` to user's `div`.